# My responsive image gallery does not transition captions correctly

Tags: css

I would quite like to have captions that fade in at the bottom of the image. Whilst debugging I have found that `div.desc` is where it should be, as in, where it should appear, but no transition so to speak.

[image: image css caption not working]

It could well be that the syntax for the way a `div.item` should `hover` is not correct.

Can someone help guide what I am doing wrong.

CSS:

```
div.img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
  color: white; 
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}
a:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

With my HTML:

```
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="/images/demo.jpg" alt="Find" width="535" height="535">
    </a>
    <div class="desc"><div class="item">This is the caption</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to transition the opacity on `.desc`, no?
If so, the reason it doesn't work is because you've selected the wrong element in your `:hover` code. You'll want to write this instead of what you have:

`a:hover + .desc`

The reason is that neither `.item` nor `.desc` is a child of your anchor tag. `.desc` is an adjacent sinling of it, and using `+` in CSS selects them. Also, you want to transition the elements that have properties to transition between (in this case, only `.desc` has its opacity changed initially).

Comment: Thanks! @MateBoy - But now .desc fades out when you hover over the div. Do you know how I can prevent this?

Comment: Well, `.desc` is always faded out unless you hover the `<a>` tag, as defined in the CSS.

Comment: I tried just hovering the <a> tag, but alas - no caption. Would you mind showing me?

Comment: But when you hover, with your mouse, over the caption div, it fades out. How can I get it so it stays on, and only fades out when the user moves off the image? Appreciate your help here :-)

Comment: Okay, sorry for my misunderstanding. There's a perfect CSS property for exactly this purpose. Add this to your `.desc` CSS: `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: YOU GENIUS! Thank you! :)))))